# How can I add JavaScript only on the front page?

Tags: 8, javascript

I created a custom Theme: filhos_do_porto using Bartik as a subtheme and I would like to add JS code only to the Front Page.

Can someone help me? (I didn’t find anything specific of D8 clear enough for someone new in Drupal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way, in your `mytheme.theme` file:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments_alter().
 */
function mytheme_page_attachments_alter(&$attachments) {
  if (\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage()) {
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'mytheme/library-name';
  }
}
```

This points to an entry in [your `mytheme.libraries.yml` file which list out what file(s) to load](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module).

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Sorry for my ignorance but I can not make it work.

A added to my filhos_do_porto.libraries.yml file the text:

front-library:
  js:
    js/onlyfront.js: {}

And added to my filhos_do_porto.theme file the text:

<?php
function mytheme_page_attachments_alter(&$attachments) {
  if (\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage()) {
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'filhos_do_porto/front-library';
  }
}


But it’s not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You dont literally use `mytheme` ... `mytheme` should be replaced with the machine name of your theme. `filhos_do_porto`

Comment: `mytheme` or `mymodule` is just a naming convention people use on here and elsewhere

Comment: It will work well also there is another trick that if u have a twig file for the front page for example - "page--front.html.twig " then you can use this code

Answer (score 1):

You can use another trick if you have a twig file for the front page then use this code below the twig file. Generally, the front page twig file name is  -

> page--front.html.twig

```
{{ attach_library('themename/library-name') }}
```